# There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "AMD64

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-studio-2012, architecture

I have a Visual Studio 2012 .Net main project with a platform target x86 specified in its build properties. The project consist of multiple C++ project and C# project. In my Configuration Manager, platform for C# project is Any CPU and for C++ project is Win32. I want to reference a 3rd party dll which is targeted for AMD64. When I add the reference, I get following warning:

> Warning: Warning: There was a mismatch between the processor
>   architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor
>   architecture of the reference "DALSA, processorArchitecture=AMD64",
>   "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider
>   changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through
>   the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures
>   between your project and references, or take a dependency on
>   references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted
>   processor architecture of your project.

If I try to change main C#  project build for platform target  x64, it complains because  external DLLs it depends on has platform target x86.

Any What am I doing wr0ng?

Comment: Sure, it is an appropriate warning.  The programmer that created that DLL said **explicitly** that it can only work in a 64-bit process.  But you are explicitly creating a 32-bit executable.  The build system would be a-miss to not warn you about that.  Maybe that programmer was wrong, .NET is pretty forgiving.  The proof is in the pudding, does it run?  If not then, well, of course it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

So you have two left shoes, and not a single right shoe. If you want to walk you should somehow get a right shoe. Either get x86 DALSA, or Win64 external DLLs.

It is impossible for a single process to run on different architectures.

The only other alternative is to make a helper process that main process would connect to with some [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) like pipe, and that would run on complementary architecture. Or wrap DLLs with COM object.